# Get logged status from API with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

React component with router in it. There's an api request in **componentDidMount** to check if user logged in. Problem is that only **LoginPage** component shows up. Could it be because of react component **App** reloads on every route change, so **state.isLogged** gets initial value ***false*** all the time? How can I fix it?

```
class App extends Component {

state = {
    logged: false,
}

async componentDidMount() {
    let logged = await getLoggedStatus(`${serverUrl}:/login`);
    this.setState({ logged: logged });
}



render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
            <Router>
                <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
                    <Route path="/login" component={loginPage} />
                    <Route exact path="/dashboard" render={() => (
                        this.state.logged ?
                        (
                            <Dashboard/>
                        ) :
                        (
                            <Redirect to="/login" />
                        )

                    )} />
                </div>
            </Router>
       </div>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that you should do are:

First: Keep a loading state so that the till the response of your API request is not available you are not taking any decision on whether to redirect to the user to login page or not.

Secondly: Check for the loading state variable to decide whether you want to make a decision or show a loader

```
class App extends Component {

    state = {
        logged: false, 
        loading: true
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        let logged = await getLoggedStatus(`${serverUrl}:/login`);
        this.setState({ logged: logged, loading: false });
    }
    render() {
        if(this.state.loading) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }
        return (
            <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
                <Router>
                    <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
                        <Route path="/login" component={loginPage} />
                        <Route exact path="/dashboard" render={() => (
                            this.state.logged ?
                            (
                                <Dashboard/>
                            ) :
                            (
                                <Redirect to="/login" />
                            )

                        )} />
                    </div>
                </Router>
           </div>
        )
    }

}
```

You code doesn't work because you have your request set up in `componentDidMount` which is executed after the render and hence you are redirected even before the request evaluates

Answer (score 1):

It will always load '/login' page since initially 'logged' is set to false.
And API in componentDidMount is an asynchronous API, by the time you will get the logged in status, it would have called render() function. Which would have loaded /login page.

On state change since the url would be pointing to /login, it will always load /login page.

There are two possible solutions.

1) Inside render function redirect user to dashborad if he is logged in.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
            <Router>
                <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
                    <Route path="/login" render={() => (
                        this.state.logged ?
                        (
                            <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
                        ) :
                        (
                            <LoginPage/>
                        )

                    )} />
                    <Route exact path="/dashboard" render={() => (
                        this.state.logged ?
                        (
                            <Dashboard/>
                        ) :
                        (
                            <Redirect to="/login" />
                        )

                    )} />
                </div>
            </Router>
       </div>
    )
}
```

2)  On getting the response from API, redirect the user to the /dashboard page.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let logged = await getLoggedStatus(`${serverUrl}:/login`);
    this.setState({ logged: logged });
    if(logged) {
        this.context.router.push('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: In this way after user logs in he'll get only dashboard page. And we'll never get to login page, also additional logic needs to be emplemented if Dashboard-2 will be added. And I also can't make second solution work (with this.router.push) ...

Comment: I added additional variable to state indicating that request to server completed, but I think there's more elegant solution to this ...

Comment: If the user is already logged in as per your server response, then why would you want to show him login page. 
I think with using another variable in state, you can show a loading page until you have received the response from API.